# How do I get std::endl to output "\r\n" if necessary?

Tags: c++, erlang

I've got the following code:

```
std::cerr << "Hello" << std::endl;
std::cerr << "World" << std::endl;
```

...which would normally be great.

**But:** I'm running it in an Erlang port program, and Erlang has done ... something to the terminal meaning that "\n" is no longer converted to CRLF, which means that my output is appearing as...

```
Hello
     World
```

What has Erlang done to my terminal? How do I detect it? How do I get `std::endl` to output `\r\n` in this case?

Note: it's (probably) not just that Erlang's ingesting stderr from my program and screwing up the line-feeds. If I use plain-ol' `printf("Hello\n")` in a NIF, I see the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `::std::endl` in the first place. It doesn't really do what you want. It always outputs `'\n'` and flushes the stream. Flushing the stream is a huge and unnecessary performance hit most of the time.

And by `'\n'` I mean exactly that. An actual, literal,`'\n'`. It doesn't do any kind of translation or anything that people think it does. Just a flat `'\n'` and a flush, even on Windows. The newline translation you get under windows is handled by the lower level `iostream` facilities and is controlled by whether or not the stream is in `binary` mode.

What Erlang has done to your terminal is probably put it in CBREAK mode. There is a good question or two on here that have answers that describe the differences between raw, cooked, and cbreak terminal driver modes in Unix.

it might be possible for you to manually set your terminal back to cooked mode. The only reason Erlang would have for doing this is that normally you only get what people typed when they hit enter. CBREAK lets you get every character as it's typed.

You can also test yourself what mode the terminal is in. Linux (and later Posix revisions) have apparently replaced the three terminal modes with various flags who's combined effect results in behavior that's very similar to the old terminal modes.

First, you probably want to use `isatty(1)` (calling `isatty` on stdout) to see if your output really is a terminal before trying anything else.

Then, you can use `tcgetattr` to read the current settings for the various bits into a `struct termios`. This structure contains a member called `c_oflag` for ouput mode bits. The relevant bits in this case are probably `ONLCR`, and maybe (but I suspect not) `OPOST`.

Comment: I assume that Erlang set the terminal to CBREAK mode for a good reason, so I don't want to set it back (it might break Erlang's output, e.g.). How do I detect the mode? With that, I can invent `my::endl` and do the correct thing...

Comment: @RogerLipscombe - I edited the comment I deleted into my answer since it answers the "How do I detect it?" part of your question.

Comment: "CBREAK lets you get every character as it's typed." -- this will be why Erlang put it in this mode. It runs a REPL by default.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe - Was my answer helpful at all?